# java.lang.StackOverflowError while adding items to list

Tags: java, stack-overflow

Trying to add items to a list and print them, it compiles, but I'm getting a run time error where theres a stack over flow error. this is what the error prints out:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
at List.<init>(List.java:5)
at List.<init>(List.java:9)
at List.<init>(List.java:9) <----- this line is repeated quite a few times
```

This is my code with the methods to adding and print the list.

```
public class List {

private AthleteNode front;

public List(){
front = null;
}

public List athletes = new List();

//add athlete to the end of the list 
public void add(Athlete a){

AthleteNode node = new AthleteNode (a);
AthleteNode current; //temp node to iterate over the list

if(front == null)
    front = node;//adds the first element

else{
    current = front;
    while (current.next !=null)
    current = current.next;
    current.next=node;
    }

}
```

Comment: A stack overflow error is almost always caused by some non-terminating recursive function, which in this case, is the infinite amount of lists within a list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your class `List`, you have a `List` instance field that gets initialized at its declaration

```
public List athletes = new List();
```

This means that every `List` will have a `List` which has a `List` which has a `List`, ad nauseam, causing a `StackOverflowError` as they are being constructed.

I'm not sure what you meant to do with that field, since you aren't using it anywhere. Just remove it.

Comment: Thank you very much, deleted that line of code, and everything works, your a life saver :)

Comment: @user3307636 You're welcome. Make sure to look at [dasblinkenlight' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23064930/438154) as well for logic corrections.